# Entity Framework doesn't want to remove rows in table with many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

Like the title is saying EF 6 doesn't want to remove rows in table (many-to-many relationship).

Tables are:

Organization

- Id (int Primary Key)
- Name (string)

OrganizationContact (many to many)

- Id (int Primary Key)
- OrganizationId (Foreign key to Organization.Id not-nullable)
- ContactTypeId (Foreign key to ContactType.Id not-nullable)
- Details (string)

ContactType

- Id (int Primary Key)
- Name (string nullable)

This is the code:

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
   db.Database.Log = x => Debug.WriteLine(x);
   var organizationDto = db.Organizations.First();
   var contactDto = organizationDto.Contacts.Last();
   organizationDto.Contacts.Remove(contactDto);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

And this is the exception:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I'll be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks!

Edit:
The log for db.SaveChanges() shows that there is no query to the database.

Comment: When you delete the `Contact`, do you want the delete to cascade?  Deleting a `Contact` would leave, possibly, an `OrginizationContact` row pointing to a row in `Contact` that doesn't exist.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to delete a OrginizationContact row and I'd like to delete only the row in OrganizationContact nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using (var db = new FIXEntities())
{
   db.Database.Log = x => Debug.WriteLine(x);
   var organizationDto = db.Organizations.First();
   var contactDto = organizationDto.Contacts.Last();
   //organizationDto.Contacts.Remove(contactDto); // not necessary

   db.Entry(contactDto).State = EntityState.Deleted;
   // or, like this if you prefer
   db.Set<OrganizationContact>().Remove(contactDto);

   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

It is not enough to just remove it from the collection property, you have to delete it. Since your many-to-many has its own primary key, EF doesn't know that you want it deleted, it just thinks you want it disassociated. So you have to delete it in order to satisfy the FK relationship that EF is complaining about in the exception.