# How to remove rows from many-to-many relationship using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, many-to-many

Tables are:

Table `Menu`

```
Id (int Primary Key)
Name (string)
virtual ICollection MenuRoles(many to many)
```

Table `RoleMenu`

```
Id (int Primary Key)
RoleId (Foreign key to Role.Id not-nullable)
MenuId (Foreign key to Menu.Id not-nullable)
```

Table `Role`

```
Id (int Primary Key)
Name (string nullable)
```

The code is:

```
var menuToUpdate = db.Menus.Include(i => i.MenuRoles).Where(i => i.ID == 1).Single();

var menuRole = menuToUpdate.MenuRoles.Where(x => x.RoleID == 0).FirstOrDefault();
menuToUpdate.MenuRoles.Remove(menuRole);

db.SaveChanges();
```

The exception I got:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated  object must be deleted.'

How can I fix this? actually, I refer to so many other questions like [Entity Framework doesn't want to remove rows in table with many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641166/entity-framework-doesnt-want-to-remove-rows-in-table-with-many-to-many-relation), But I don't think they are what I want. I want to use remove method just like the code above to fix the exception. Thanks a lot

Comment: `But I don't think they are what I want.` Did you try any of the suggestions there?

Comment: So you want to use a method `just like the code above` that doesn't work and don't want to use suggestions others made?

Comment: Actually, I have tried other suggestions, But I get the same exception. My scenario is a little different with others. in model Menu, I define an ICollection<MenuRole> but not ICollection<Role>, I am not sure whether it's the reason I got the same exception after trying so many solution.